# Profile info block moved bottom in user card if the nickname is too long

Tags: bug, design, user-card

> [image] [image]

Probably, need to truncate the name.

Comment: It's already truncated, probably the width became smaller at some point and they didn't change the algorithm to match the truncate amount with the new design.